# Missing parameter in a model

Tags: mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability, model, parameterization

I read a textbook on statistical models in genomics and authors give an example of one.
Where $\textbf{d} = \{d_1, d_2, \dots, d_n\}$ are some data and $f$ and $\epsilon$ are parameters:
$$ P (\textbf{d}, f, \epsilon) = P (\textbf{d} |f, \epsilon) P ( f, \epsilon) = \left[ \prod_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{g_i} P(d_i | g_i, \epsilon) P(g_i | f) \right]  P ( f, \epsilon) $$
But I can't go through their calculations. For example:

I undestand this step. It just a chain rule:
$$ P (\textbf{d}, f, \epsilon) =  P (\textbf{d} |f, \epsilon) P ( f, \epsilon) $$

Bacause of independce of each $d_i$ I can write:

$$ P (\textbf{d} |f, \epsilon) P ( f, \epsilon) = \left[ \prod_{i=1}^{n} P(d_i | f, \epsilon)  \right]  P ( f, \epsilon) $$

Due to presense of unobserved variable $\textbf{g}$ I can do a summation over all $g_i$:

$$ = \left[ \prod_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{g_i} P(d_i | f, g_i, \epsilon) \right]  P ( f, \epsilon) $$

Then authors say that $d_i$ in independent of $f$. So I conclude we can write the equation without $f$:
$$ = \left[ \prod_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{g_i} P(d_i | g_i, \epsilon) \right]  P ( f, \epsilon) $$

But authors gave another answer:

$$ = \left[ \prod_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{g_i} P(d_i | g_i, \epsilon) P(g_i | f) \right]  P ( f, \epsilon) $$

Could you help to understand where I did a mistake or from where $P(g_i | f)$ did come?